# $str_result showing up before form is submitted

Tags: php, jquery, database, forms

I am new to PHP and HTML coding so I'm sorry if this seems very obvious.

My problem is: Once a user has logged in and goes to the homepage of my website, before they click submit on the form, the `$str_result` and `$str_comments` are showing up.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
//If connected to the database get services names from database and write out DropDownMenu
        mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
        $query = "SELECT ID, Name FROM categories ORDER BY Name";
        $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
        if (!$result) die("Query failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $str_options .= "<option value= '" . $row[ 'ID'] . "'>";
                $str_options .= $row['Name'];
                $str_options .= "</option>";
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);

// Your code here to handle a successful verification
$str_result = "<h2>Thanks for your search! Services avaliable are:" .
$category = clean_string($db_server, $_POST["categories"]) . "</h2>";
?>

<!--form-->
<form method="post" action="nihome.php"><p>I am searching for</p>
<select name="categories"><?php echo $str_options; ?></select>
<br /> 
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
//Capture form data, if anything was submitted
if (isset($_POST['categories']) and ($_POST['categories'] != '')){
$category = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['categories']);

// create the SQL query
$query = "SELECT salon.ID AS ID, categories.Name as Category, salon.salon_name AS Salon, services.name AS Service, servicesoffered.price AS price FROM services 
    JOIN categories ON services.cID = categories.ID 
    JOIN servicesoffered ON servicesoffered.serviceID = services.ID
    JOIN salon ON servicesoffered.salonID = salon.ID WHERE categories.ID=$category";
                    // query the database
                    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
                    $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
                    if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));

// if there are any rows, print out the contents
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$str_result .= '<h3>' . $row['Salon'] . ',</h3><p>' .
            $row['Service'] . ", £" . 
            $row['price'] .'</p>' .<a href="salonpage.php?salonid=' . $row['ID'] .'">Click here to view or add to salon reviews</a>';

} 
if($str_result == "") $str_result = "<h2>No services found</h2>";

} else {
$str_result = '<h2>No service was requested</h2>';
}
mysqli_close($db_server);

echo $str_result;
echo $str_comments;
?>
```

Comment: You're missing an `'` before the `<a href="salonpage.php?...`

Comment: Why the downvotes? The OP has clearly stated he's new to PHP and he's made an effort.  He's asking for help not for someone to write the code for him

Comment: people jsut downvote without reading the question !!! wtf

Answer (score 0):

You should actually write an `if()` where it says `// Your code here to handle a successful verification`:

```
if (!empty($_POST) /* && all your other validation routines */)
  {
  $str_result = "<h2>Thanks for your search! Services avaliable are:" .
  $category = clean_string($db_server, $_POST["categories"]) . "</h2>";
  }
```

Besides, you're missing an `'` before `<a href="salonpage.php?`

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your script, you set this:

```
$str_result = "<h2>Thanks for your search! Services avaliable are:"
```

(Also, there's a trailing dot on that line, propably supposed to be a `;`)

And then you check the following:

```
if($str_result == "") $str_result = "<h2>No services found</h2>";
```

Which of course never happens, because it's never an empty string to begin with.

If you do something like this your `if` statement at the end should fire correctly, and you should end up with the expected result:

```
$str_result = "";

[ ... ]

if (isset($_POST['categories']) and ($_POST['categories'] != '')){
    // Set it inside this if statement.
    // So it will stay empty when nothing was submitted
    $str_result = "<h2>Thanks for your search! Services avaliable are:"
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked! Thank you very much I was at a complete loss!

Answer (score 0):

YOu should try this

```
if($str_result == "")
{ $str_result = "<h2>No services found</h2>";

} else {
$str_result = '<h2>No service was requested</h2>';
}
mysqli_close($db_server);

echo $str_result;
echo $str_comments;
}
```

Here two things are very important.
 **First:**

```
if($str_result == "")
    { $str_result = "<h2>No services found</h2>";

    }
```

You forgot the starting `{` and
 **Second:**
 you should keep

```
echo $str_result;
    echo $str_comments;
```

inside `}` which will make it execute only when the buttons are clicked. Hope this helps

**And**

```
$str_result = "<h2>Thanks for your search! Services avaliable are:" ;
```

end it with the `;`

Answer (score 0):

first correct this line
you should make single quote before `<a href=........>'`

```
`$row['price'] .'</p>' .'<a href="salonpage.php?salonid=' . $row['ID'] .'">Click here to view or add to salon reviews</a>';
```

and 
encapsulate `$str_result` and `$str_comments` in `isset` then they will just appear only when the `categories` variable exist.

Answer (score 0):

you should enclose the code inside a if condition.

i.e

```
if (!empty($_POST){
if($str_result == "") $str_result = "<h2>No services found</h2>";
} else {
$str_result = '<h2>No service was requested</h2>';
}
}
```

also, You're missing a (apostrophe) ' before the `<a href="salonpage.php?`